# cannot access the array using php

Tags: php, arrays

i have created an array using php something like this

```
$array1=array()

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $array1[$i]=somevalue;
  for($y=0;$y<$i;$y++)
  {
    print_r($array1[$y]);
  }
}
```

it does not print the value.

Comment: Can you please write your array? your array on top has no vallues.. ;)

Comment: its a new array which i am creating

Comment: something like this doesn't help us find your actual problem. Are you getting any errors? have you got all error reporting turned on. What is your actual code?

Comment: are you aware the second loop will be printing the array many times even when [0] is set but the rest are not?

Comment: there are some syntax errors in your code.   
If it's the real code you posted here, you have to correct them and it will work.

if you're actually running another code, you have to post it here.

Comment: also try print $array1[$y] instead of print_r($array1[$y])

Comment: i am aware that the second loop will print many times, but it is not fetching the array contents inside the second loop.

Comment: line $array1=array() missing ;

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, you should move the inner loop out:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $array1[$i]=somevalue;
}

for($y=0;$y<5;$y++)
{
    print_r($array1[$y]);
}
```

Comment: $i is not going to be available outside the first for loop

Comment: @Belinda: Copy/paste programming is bad :) Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this code, the only change i made was putting a semicolon in the first line ;)

```
<?php

$array1=array();

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $array1[$i]="abcd";
  for($y=0;$y<$i;$y++)
  {
    print_r($array1[$y]);
  }
}

?>
```

Output:
abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jon's answer:

```
$array1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $array1[$i]=somevalue;
}

$count = count($array1);

for($y=0;$y<$count;$y++)
{
    print_r($array1[$y]);
}
```

You **can** put the count function in the for loop, but that's bad practice. Also, if you are trying to get the value of EVERY value in the array, try a foreach instead.

```
$array1 = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $array1[$i]=somevalue;
}
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
  print_r($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way how `print_r` works, it is silly to put it inside a loop, this will give you actual output and is error free :).

```
$array1=array();

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $array1[$i]='somevalue';
}
print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($y=0;$y<$i;$y++)
```

Your display loop isn't displaying the entry you've just added as $array[$i], because you're looping $y while it's **less than** $i

```
for($y=0;$y<=$i;$y++)
```